# Cyclic movement of div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html

[image]

This is the template of the webpage I want to create. I want the contents of the div's(div-1 to div-8) to rotate among them.

Is there any method other than changing the position of div's using the timer functions.

Can the contents of the div be moved, with the div at their positions.

In html5 is there any feature that can be advantageous to this situation

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Maybe you can try saving the contents as `DocumentFragment`s and only rotate the contents without moving the divs.

Comment: Fac each div I've written functions such that the div comes to its original position in 30 seconds. The code has been same with variation only in the positions due to the original position of the div. I want to know is there any better way to get that affect. @Sarath

Comment: Can you show it with an example in `jsfiddle` . I've little idea about `DocumentFragment`s. ThankYou @Tzach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing it using keyframes. 
I have used jquery _obj.keyframes method along with jquery Keyframes plugin to incorporate the solution.
You can check the code on github: 
[github repo](https://github.com/ashishahs2000/Rotating-Divs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery path plug-in e.g.:

```
$(_oObj).animate({
    path : new $.path.arc({
        center : [_nAxis, _nAxis],
        radius : _nRadius,
        start : _nStart,
        end : _nStart,
        dir : 1
    })
}, 1, "swing", function() {
});
```